# A question about a claim in "No occurrence obstructions in geometric complexity theory"

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds, algebraic-complexity, permanent, determinant

It the new preprint

- Peter Bürgisser, Christian Ikenmeyer, Greta Panova, "[No occurrence obstructions in geometric complexity theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06431)", 2016

it is stated that

> 1.3. Conjecture (Mulmuley and Sohoni 2001). For all $c \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ we have $X_{11}^{m^c-m}per_m \notin \Omega_{m^c}$ for infinitely many $m$.
>
> 1.4. Conjecture (Mulmuley and Sohoni 2001). For all $c \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$,
>   for infinitely many $m$, there exists a partition $\lambda$ occurring in $\mathbb{C}[Z_{m^c,m}]$ but not in $\mathbb{C}[\Omega_{m^c}]$.
>
> 1.5. Theorem. Let $n, d, m$ be positive integers with $n\geq m^{25}$ and $\lambda \vdash nd$. If $\lambda$ occurs in $\mathbb{C}[Z_{n,m}]$, then $\lambda$ also occurs in $\mathbb{C}[Z_{n}]$. In particular, Conjecture 1.4 is false.

and it is claimed that

> While our main result, Theorem 1.5, rules out the possibility of proving
>   the Conjecture 1.3 via occurrence obstructions, there still remains the possibility that one may succeed so by comparing multiplicities.

The phrase "there still remains the possibility that one may succeed so by comparing multiplicities" seems to suggest this is the only path left for moving forward on GCT strategy. Is my interpretation true and is there an easy way to understand the strategy of this approach? What is the consequence if this also fails?